# Update Dictionary from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary

I tried to get all key/value of `localStorage` and get it to update my dictionary `keywordDict` as the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var store = allStorage();
  console.log(store);
  $.ajax({
    url: '/myUrl/Template/hint',
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      'store': store
    }
  }).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data.keywordDict);
  });
})
```

`allStorage()` get all key/value of `localStorage`

```
 function allStorage() {

      var archive = {},
        keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
        i = keys.length;

      while (i--) {
        archive[keys[i]] = localStorage.getItem(keys[i]);
      }

      return archive;
    }
```

From console my localStorage return key/value as below:

```
{hello{{hello}}: "hello{{hello}}", hello{{hello}: "hello{{hello}", hello{{hello: "hello{{hello", hello{{hell: "hello{{hell", hello{{hel: "hello{{hel", …}

h : "h"
he:"he"
hel:"hel"
hell:"hell"
hello:"hello"
hello{:"hello{"
hello{{:"hello{{"
hello{{h:"hello{{h"
hello{{he:"hello{{he"
hello{{hel:"hello{{hel"
hello{{hell:"hello{{hell"
hello{{hello:"hello{{hello"
hello{{hello}:"hello{{hello}"
hello{{hello}}:"hello{{hello}}"
```

In my route `/myUrl/Template/hint`, I updated my `keywordDict` as below:

```
@app.route("/myUrl/Template/hint", methods=['GET','POST'])
def gethint():
    keywordDict = {}

    keyword = request.form.get('store')

    print "keyword is ",keyword

    if keyword:
        keywordDict.update({keyword:keyword})

    print keywordDict

    return jsonify(keywordDict=keywordDict)
```

However, my `keywordDict` never get updated because `keyword` is always return `none`.

Then, if I went go to print `request.form`, it return value as below:

```
(
    [
        ('store[hello{{hel]', u 'hello{{hel'),
        ('store[hello{{hello}]', u 'hello{{hello}'),
        ('store[hello{]', u 'hello{'),
        ('store[h]', u 'h'),
        ('store[hel]', u 'hel'),
        ('store[hello{{h]', u 'hello{{h'),
        ('store[hello]', u 'hello'),
        ('store[he]', u 'he'),
        ('store[hell]', u 'hell'),
        ('store[cloneobjIndex]', u ''),
        ('store[hello{{hello}}]', u 'hello{{hello}}'),
        ('store[hello{{hello]', u 'hello{{hello'),
        ('store[hello{{hell]', u 'hello{{hell'),
        ('store[hello{{he]', u 'hello{{he'),
        ('store[hello{{]', u 'hello{{')
    ]
)
```

However, still my `keywordDict` does not updated.

What is wrong to my `keywordDict`, how can I update key/value according to my `localStorage`? Thanks.

Comment: seems the problem is .get('store'),maybe you should check the python grammar. i don't know python,,,so , can't help you

Comment: @xianshenglu, thanks. I'm quite sure `request.form.get` is to get value from form.

Comment: i guess the problem is 'store' in the API .get()

Comment: @xianshenglu, I guess yes it is, so I just print `request.form` alone, and it return result as in my question above, its data type is `ImmutableMultiDict.`

Comment: You can try serialising the object as json string when you're passing it from ajax and deserialise in python.

Comment: @AbhishekNair, thank very much, I change to this `var store = JSON.stringify(allStorage());` and call in python as this `storage = request.form.get('store')`, so I can get my dict updated. Thanks :)

Comment: @HouyNarun So I'll put it as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try serialising the object as json string when you're passing it from ajax and deserialise in python.